# Update a column on update of others columns properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like know a properly way to change a column value if others columns change, i know the classic way with one case `return self.prices_updated_at = Time.zone.now if currency_changed?`

But i dont know how write it more properly than that when i have many cases

```
return unless currency_changed? || price1_changed? || price2_changed? ||
                  price3_changed? || price4_changed? ||
                  price5_changed? || price6_changed?

    self.prices_updated_at = Time.zone.now
```

Comment: While you could use a tangled web of callbacks and ActiveModel::Dirty it would probally be a better idea to create a service object that handles to the logic of updating the record. https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/refactor-ruby-rails-service-object/

Comment: But I would also consider if prices should be a seperate table and `prices_updated_at` should actually be obtained by doing `MAX(prices.updated_at)` - you may be cramming way too much into a single model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [changed_attributes](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Dirty/changed_attributes)

```
return unless (changed_attributes.keys & %w[currency price1 price2 price3 price4 price5 price6]).any?
self.prices_updated_at = Time.zone.now
```

Comment: This will be updating the column all the time because even is `changed_attributes.keys` is empty, `[] & []` returns an empty array and therefore the condition will always be `true`.

Comment: @spickermann `unless []` will return false

Comment: Yeah, but no matter, if there are any `changed_attributes.keys` or not the condition, will always trigger the return.

Comment: Ohh yes correct we will have to use ([] & []).any? to check if any attribute was changed. Thanks @spickermann will update the answer.